# Getting The Number Of 2d Arrays In An Array of 2d Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, size

I have a really dumb question. Please forgive it's late and I am tired. :)

I have a 2d array of ints defined as follows:

```
int[,] myArray = new int[,] // array of 7 int[,] arrays
{
    { 1, 10 }, // 0
    { 2, 20 }, // 1
    { 3, 30 }, // 2
    { 4, 40 }, // 3
    { 5, 50 }, // 4
    { 6, 60 }, // 5
    { 7, 70 }, // 6                
};
```

As you can see the array consists of 7 int[,] arrays.

When I call *myArray.Length* it results in 14. What I need is 7. How do I get the number of int[,] arrays? What is the method to call (the result I am expecting is 7).

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That ***is not*** an array of 2D arrays - it is a single 2D array. As already noted, the dimensions are given by `myArray.GetLength(dimension)`. It is not an array with "7 int[,] arrays" - it is simply a 7-by-2 array.

If you want an array of arrays (actually, a vector of vectors), it is:

```
int[][] myArray = {
    new int[] {1,10}, // alternative: new[]{1,10} - the "int" is optional
    new int[] {2,20},
    new int[] {3,30},
    new int[] {4,40},
    new int[] {5,50},
    new int[] {6,60},
    new int[] {7,70},
};
```

and then the  `7` is `myArray.Length`.

Comment: i like that way! i think i will use your suggestion it looks more elegant! :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [GetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to get the length of one dimension.

```
myArray.GetLength(0)
```

Try the following lines:

```
 Console.WriteLine(myArray.GetLength(0)); 
 Console.WriteLine(myArray.GetLength(1));
```

You will get

```
7
2
```